# wc_get_products and pagination in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a REST API plugin. In some API, I need to get list of all products. It's fairly simple:

```
$args = array( 'limit' => 10 );
$wc_products = wc_get_products( $args );
```

But I also need to construct a pagination array listing items like: `current_page`, `total_items`, `next_page_url`, `prev_page_url`

I'm not able to figure out how to get `total_items` & `total_pages`, I tried this:

```
// for total_pages
$wc_products->max_num_pages // it returns NULL
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `paginate` parameter to get `total` and `max_num_pages`:

```
$args = ['limit' => 10, 'paginate' => true];
$wc_products = wc_get_products( $args );

echo $wc_products->total.' products found\n';
echo 'Page 1 of '.$wc_products->max_num_pages.'\n';
```